# Mysql Partitioning Query

Tags: mysql, partitioning, mysql-5.7

i have created partitions on pricing table. below is the alter statement.

```
ALTER TABLE `price_tbl` 
PARTITION BY HASH(man_code)
PARTITIONS 87;
```

one partition consists of 435510 records. total records in price_tbl is 6 million.

EXPLAIN query showing only one partion is used for the query . Still the query takes **3-4 sec** to execute. below is the query

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT vrimg.image_cap_id,vm.man_name,vr.range_code,vr.range_name,vr.range_url, MIN(`finance_rental`) AS from_price, vd.der_id AS vehicle_id FROM `range_tbl` vr 
    LEFT JOIN `image_tbl` vrimg ON vr.man_code = vrimg.man_code AND vr.type_id = vrimg.type_id AND vr.range_code = vrimg.range_code 
    LEFT JOIN `manufacturer_tbl` vm ON vr.man_code = vm.man_code AND vr.type_id = vm.type_id 
    LEFT JOIN `derivative_tbl` vd ON vd.man_code=vm.man_code AND vd.type_id = vr.type_id AND vd.range_code=vr.range_code 
    LEFT JOIN `price_tbl` vp ON vp.vehicle_id = vd.der_id AND vd.type_id = vp.type_id AND vp.product_type_id=1 AND vp.maintenance_flag='N'  AND vp.man_code=164 
    AND vp.initial_rentals_id =(SELECT rental_id FROM `rentals_tbl` WHERE rental_months='9') 
    AND vp.annual_mileage_id =(SELECT annual_mileage_id FROM `mileage_tbl` WHERE annual_mileage='8000') 
    WHERE vr.type_id = 1 AND vm.man_url = 'audi' AND vd.type_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY vd.der_id
```

Result of EXPLAIN.

[image]

Same query without partitioning takes 3-4 sec.
Query with partitioning takes 2-3 sec.

how we can increase query performance as it is too slow yet.

**UPDATE: attached create table structure.**

1. price table - This consists 6 million records

```
CREATE TABLE `price_tbl` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lender_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `man_code` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `vehicle_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_type_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `initial_rentals_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `term_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `annual_mileage_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `maintenance_flag` enum('Y','N') DEFAULT NULL,
  `finance_rental` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthly_rental` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `maintenance_payment` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `initial_payment` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doc_fee` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`type_id`,`man_code`),
  KEY `type_id` (`type_id`),
  KEY `vehicle_id` (`vehicle_id`),
  KEY `term_id` (`term_id`),
  KEY `product_type_id` (`product_type_id`),
  KEY `finance_rental` (`finance_rental`),
  KEY `type_id_2` (`type_id`,`vehicle_id`),
  KEY `maintenanace_idx` (`maintenance_flag`),
  KEY `lender_idx` (`lender_id`),
  KEY `initial_idx` (`initial_rentals_id`),
  KEY `man_code_idx` (`man_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5830708 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (man_code)
PARTITIONS 87 */
```

2. derivative table - This consists 18k records.

```
CREATE TABLE `derivative_tbl` (
  `type_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_cap_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body_style_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fuel_type_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `man_code` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `range_code` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model_code` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_intro_year` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_disc_year` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_last_spec_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `der_id` (`der_id`),
  KEY `type_id` (`type_id`),
  KEY `man_code` (`man_code`),
  KEY `range_code` (`range_code`),
  KEY `model_code` (`model_code`),
  KEY `body_idx` (`body_style_id`),
  KEY `capcodeidx` (`der_cap_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

3. range table - This consists 1k records

```
CREATE TABLE `range_tbl` (
  `type_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `man_code` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `range_code` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `range_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `range_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `range_code` (`range_code`),
  KEY `type_id` (`type_id`),
  KEY `man_code` (`man_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: 87 partitions 400k records each is 5-6 times over 6kk. WTF? And does the query gives wrong result?

Comment: Please don't say `LEFT` unless the 'right' table is optional.  `AND  vm.man_url = 'audi'` forces `vm` to be a regular `JOIN`.  (I don't know about the rest.)

Comment: @RickJames prices are not compulsory in this case that why added LEFT JOIN.

Comment: It seems reasonable that it only uses one partition, as you partition by man_code and you have a filter man_code=164, so it only needs to access the specific partition. But what is the question here?

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE rentals_tbl; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE mileage_tbl; and C) price_tbl; ?

Comment: @WilsonHauck added table info.

Comment: why this question is downvoted?

Comment: @jit           Thanks for A), B), C) SHOW CREATE TABLE's.  Still need SHOW CREATE TABLE for D) image_tbl, E) manufacturer_tbl; F) rentals_tbl; G) mileage_tbl; to complete data type analysis for matching data types.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from `LEFT`, but I can't prove it.

```
    LEFT JOIN  `price_tbl` vp  ON vp.vehicle_id = vd.der_id
      AND  vp.man_code=164
      AND ...
```

says "check to see if `price_tbl` has row(s) with `man_code=164 AND ...`, but if it doesn't continue to evaluate everything else.

If you *only* want rows with 164, then change to just `JOIN` there (and perhaps elsewhere).

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  It looks like `type_id_2` might start with `man_code`?  If so, the `PARTITION BY HASH(man_code)` provides *no* speedup.

I have yet to find any use case for `PARTITION BY HASH` that speeds up queries over what could be done by a non-partitioned table with suitably designed indexes.